# Jetpack Compose experimental material API

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Jetpack Compose and following Google's codelabs. I tried some material3
functions and get this error message :

```
This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.
```

And it suggested me to use this option:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
```

When I look releases it says it is stable but still got experimental message. How to fix tihs error or above code is mandatory?

The code I tried to use is this:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.heightIn
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Search
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.basiclayouts.ui.theme.BasicLayoutsTheme

@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    TextField( // error message 
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {},
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors( // error message
        ),
        placeholder = {
            Text(stringResource(R.string.placeholder_search))
        },
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(min = 56.dp)
    )
}
```

I looked other people who encounter same problem but didn't find solution about it. Also checked Google docs https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ExperimentalLayoutApi#ExperimentalLayoutApi() but there is no explanation here as well.

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of the dependencies?

Comment: I am but specify the material3 version by its own solved the problem. Thank you for mention.

Answer (score 2):

Add an annotation either `@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)` or `@ExperimentalMaterial3Api` to your `SearchBar` composable function. Adding these annotations will resolve your error.